# Pyspark UDF experience

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

there.
I am very new to Pyspark and I am learning the UDF myself. I realize UDF sometimes will slow down your code. I want to know about your experience. What UDF function did you apply(cannot be achieved with Pyspark code only). Is there any useful UDF function that helps you clean the data? Except for the Pyspark document, is there any source that can help me learn the UDF function?

Answer (score 0):

You can find most of your needed functionality within the standard library functions spark has.
import pyspark.sql.functions  - Check the docs here `https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions`

Now, sometimes you do have to create custom UDF's but be aware that it does slow down since spark has to evaluate it for every dataframe row.
try to avoid this as much as you can.

When you don't have any other option, use it, but try to minimize the complexity and the external libraries you use.

Another approach is to use an RDD, which means you convert your dataframe to an rdd (`MYDF.rdd`)

And right after you call `mapPartitions` or `map` which accept a function that manipulate your data.
It basically sends chunks each time as a list of spark `Row` entity.

Read more about `mapPartitions`   or `map` here: `https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-vs-mappartitions-transformation/`